# Javascript how to make function work on other function

Tags: javascript, html

I've just started learn JavaScript and wanted to try something. 
How can I make JavaScript function work on other function? Like, I want when you click on a div, other div will have `background-color:yellow;` (or `x.style.backgroundColor="yellow";` in JS), like this:

```
<div onclick="yellow">Click me to paint the other div in yellow</div>
<div id="painted">I should be painted yellow if you click the above div!</div>
```

In C-language I know it can be possible if you call recursion so I tried use it though I don't know.
Of course it didn't succeed but there's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/huzayuhi/1/edit) if you want to look.
**Q: How can I paint a div in yellow background with other div function using JavaScript?** 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to attach the function with parenthesis like `fillYellow()`,

```
<div onclick="fillYellow()">Click me to paint the other div in yellow</div>
<div id="painted">I should be painted yellow if you click the above div!</div>

<script>
function fillYellow(){
    document.getElementById('painted').style.background = "yellow";
}
</script>
```

Inside this function get the `painted` div by it's id and apply background color for this div.

Comment: Thanks.
But I have another question (quick) and I don't want to open another question, it'll be waste.
My new question is: Why isn't this code working? [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wacakuba/1/edit)
I want to make the div white after 3 seconds and it doesn't work...
THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: @rolory See my answer below. This is the explanation for "Why isn't this code working?" in you JSBIN

Answer (score 1):

You should have `document.getElementById("backgroundChange");` instead of `getElementById("backgroundChange");` and it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

As your question was *"How can I make JavaScript function work on other function?"* I started to think maybe you're really talking about doing something event-driven.

Therefore, why not consider this (slightly more advanced) solution

1. When you click a `<div>`, you fire a custom "paint" event at every `<div>`.

   - The event fired at itself is different to at other `<div>`s.
2. When a `<div>` `node` sees a "paint" event `e`, it applies `e.style` to `node.style`

The code would look like this

```
function paintEvent(style) { // function make a custom event
    var ev = new Event('paint');
    ev.style = style;
    return ev;
}

function applyPaint(node, style) { // function to style a node
    var key;
    for (key in style) { // loop over object
        node.style[key] = style[key];
    }
}

function paintHandler(e) { // function to fire when you see a "paint" event
    applyPaint(this, e.style);
}

function clickHandler(e) { // function to fire when you see a "click" event
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
        i,
        paint = paintEvent({'background-color': 'yellow'});
    this.dispatchEvent(paintEvent({'background-color': 'red'}));
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) { // loop over array-like
        if (divs[i] !== this)
            divs[i].dispatchEvent(paint);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () { // when the Window has loaded
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) { // loop over array-like
        divs[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler); // attach the handlers
        divs[i].addEventListener('paint', paintHandler);
    }
});
```

### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PktZY/)

Comment: I tried to write it clearly for you. Although every part of it is linked, I hope that the way it's broken down into the separate functions means you can actually follow the logic in each bit without having to keep going in and back to read it all.

Answer (score 0):

Your yellow event handler should look up the div with the id "painted" and then add a class to it which will give it yellow text.

This is one way ( a simple one) but where are a number of other similar ways to accomplish this.